# How can I remove HTML comments in my Facelets?

Tags: jsf, comments, facelets

I would like to remove all HTML comments from my facelets before delivering to end users. Does any standard approach exist?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There are actually two ways:

1. To remove **all** comments, add this to `web.xml`:

   ```xml
    <context-param>
        <param-name>jakarta.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
   ```

   or when you're still on JSF 3.x/2.x:

   ```xml
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
   ```

   or when you're still on JSF 1.x which doesn't use Facelets as default view technology yet:

   ```xml
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
   ```
2. To remove *specific* comments only, use [`<ui:remove>`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/4.0/vdldoc/ui/remove).

   ```html
    <ui:remove><!-- This is a HTML comment. --></ui:remove>
   ```

Comment: Didn't know that, and i've been working with JSF/Facelets for 1 year.

Comment: @Koray: By reading docs (context param is mentioned in page 11-3 of [JSF 2 spec](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jsf-2.0-fr-full-oth-JSpec/jsf-2_0-fr-spec.pdf)).

Comment: @BalusC This is the draft, isn 't it? Is there no final version?

Comment: @Koray: no draft, "fr" is final, see also http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jsf-2.0-fr-full-oth-JSpec

Comment: ..and for Jakarta Faces the parameter is `jakarta.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS`, see [Javadoc](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/3.0/apidocs/constant-values.html)

Comment: Indeed. That's just part of the javax -> jakarta migration.

Answer (score 1):

With `jakarta`, to remove all comments before sending pages to the clients, add this to your web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>jakarta.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```