# h:commandbutton calls wrong action method

Tags: jsf-2, action, commandbutton

I faced a interesting problem here. When I click commandButton, it calls wrong action method even button has not action attribute. What is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That may happen when the EL expression which you intented to use as a method expression is been evaluated as a value expression.

For example, when you have outcommented it using a HTML comment while not having configured Facelets to skip comments.

```
<!-- <h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit()}" /> -->
```

The HTML comments namely doesn't stop EL expressions like `#{bean.submit()}` from being evaluated. It will ultimately generate HTML output with the return value of `#{bean.submit()}` inlined in the `action` attribute.

To naildown the root cause in your case, you should be creating and providing a fullworthy [SSCCE](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info).

#### See also:

- [How can I remove HTML comments in my Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388109/how-can-i-remove-html-comments-in-my-facelets/3388169#3388169)
- [Outcommented Facelets code still invokes EL expressions like #{bean.action()} and causes javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException on #{bean.action}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14692560/managed-bean-method-expression-treated-as-a-value-expression/14692966#14692966)