# How to add an empty element in a JSF panelGrid?

Tags: jsf, datagrid, components, element

How do I add an empty element in a JSF panelGrid?

*This is my full table:*

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <h:outputLabel value="row1"/>
    <h:outputLabel value="row2"/>

    <h:outputLabel value="row1"/>
    <h:outputLabel value="row2"/>

    <h:outputLabel value="row1"/>
    <h:outputLabel value="row2"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

How do I add an empty element? What is the advised way? (adding an empty outputlabel? This does not feel correct.)

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <h:outputLabel value="row1"/>
    <h:outputLabel value="row2"/>

    <!-- This need to be emtpy -->
    <h:outputLabel value="row2"/>

    <h:outputLabel value="row1"/>
    <h:outputLabel value="row2"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: "Empty" does mean only its `value` should remain empty? Why does not this `<h:outputLabel value=""/>` suffice, if such is a case? For what purpose is an empty `<h:outputLabel>` needed? It should be as good as it does not exist at all. Doesn't it?

Comment: Ola! Adding <!-- empty --> does work! Is this the best practice? Please answer. I need an empty cell for layout reasons.

Comment: All other potential readers of this post should have already precisely understood the question but I have not yet understood - a silly mind :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use an empty `<h:panelGroup>`.

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <h:outputLabel value="row1"/>
    <h:outputLabel value="row2"/>

    <h:panelGroup />
    <h:outputLabel value="row2"/>

    <h:outputLabel value="row1"/>
    <h:outputLabel value="row2"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

#### See also:

- [Java EE tutorial - `<h:panelGrid>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnarf.html#bnasc)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, are you in basic HTML terms very well aware of when you should be using `<h:outputLabel>` instead of `<h:outputText>`? If not, carefully read [Purpose of the h:outputLabel and its "for" attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17544141/purpose-of-the-houtputlabel-and-its-for-attribute).

Comment: This puzzles me: also <!-- empty cell --> represents an empty cell... what to prefer?

Comment: Bad idea. Facelets can be configured to remove comments. See also e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388109/how-can-i-remove-html-comments-in-my-facelets

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to change dynamically the content of the cell, and need only an empty cell, probabily using *<h:outputText/>* is more efficient than adding a component *<h:panelGroup />* to the page structure:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
  <h:outputLabel value="row1"/>
  <h:outputLabel value="row2"/>

  <h:outputText/>
  <h:outputLabel value="row2"/>

  <h:outputLabel value="row1"/>
  <h:outputLabel value="row2"/>
</h:panelGrid>
```