# Is there any way to write comments using jstl?

Tags: jsp, jstl, el, jsp-tags

As a good coding practice we should not use scriptlet inside jsp .
I want to write comments in my jsp for other developers but don't want to show it to client when page gets converted to html.

Is there any way we can write following code using jstl or El ?

```
<% 
//for perfromance we redirect control to this jsp
//as this jsp don't load unused dom ,css , js
%>
```

I couldn't find any thing in internet on this ?

Comment: why not use JSP comments ? `<%-- comment --%>`

Comment: FYI: JSP's successor Facelets can be configured to skip plain HTML comments during rendering. See also a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/q/3388109

Comment: I am looking for <c:out> kinda tag to write comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

no,

you cannot write a comment using EL Language, however you can use JSP comments which will be hidden from user and no need for scriptlets

```
         <%-- This is a Hidden Comment.  --%>
```